# Resolving virtual method overloads across base classes

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, name-lookup, ambiguous-call

Visual Studio 2013.

Given:

```
class base_1
{
public:
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
};

class base_2
{
public:
    virtual void foo(int, double) = 0;
};

class join_1_2 : public virtual base_1, public virtual base_2
{};
```

I have a sink:

```
void sink(join_1_2 &param)
{
    param.foo(42, 3.14);
}
```

But I get the following compiler errors:

> error C2385: ambiguous access of 'foo'
>
> could be the 'foo' in base 'base_1'
>
> or could be the 'foo' in base 'base_2'
>
> error C2660: 'base_1::foo' : function does not take 2 arguments
>
> error C3861: 'foo': identifier not found

I know I can resolve this issue with:

```
param.base_2::foo(42, 3.14);
```

But as you can imagine, virtual inheritance is already one sin too many I have to live with. I'm probably going to write an adapter. But I don't understand what is preventing the compiler from trying to resolve foo in base_2. My colleague believes it to be a compiler error, but I'm not so quick to blame the vendor.

What does the C++ spec say about resolving overloaded virtual methods across base classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed ambiguity according to the standard, but you can use `using` or specify the base class explicitly:

```
class join_1_2 : public virtual base_1, public virtual base_2
{
public:
    using base_1::foo;
    using base_2::foo;
};

void sink(join_1_2 &param)
{
    param.base_2::foo(42, 3.14);
}
```

**7.3.3 The using declaration**

> For the purpose of overload resolution, the functions which are introduced by a using-declaration into a
>   derived class will be treated as though they were members of the derived class.

Answer (score 4):

The rule of thumb is that functions in different scopes don't overload - here our `foo`s are in different scopes. If you want them to overload, you'll want to bring them in with a *using-declaration*:

```
class join_1_2 : public virtual base_1, public virtual base_2
{
public:
    using base_1::foo;
    using base_2::foo;
};
```

Comment: 1. could you provide some quotes to the rule.?  2. Is there any other way to get this situation without class member lookup/multiple inheritance.?